# Convert binary string to hex for curl request

Tags: python, curl, hex, binarystream

I have a struct pack like

```
def encode_number(value):
    return struct.pack('>I', value)


def decode_number(raw):
    return int.from_bytes(raw, byteorder='big')
```

`>>> encode_number(1)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01'`

`>>> decode_number(b'\x00\x00\x00\x01')
1`

while the transcations given via curl are given in Hex like 
`curl http://localhost:26657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx=0x01`

So 0x01 is 1 in hex,how do you convert your binary string to hex easily for curl command ? (preferable in a linux terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a google search and came across this: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65280/binary-to-hexadecimal-and-decimal-in-a-shell-script

The example they use for Binary to Hex (Bash/Linux Terminal):

```
$ printf '%x\n' "$((2#101010101))"
155
```

Comment: so do you `curl http://localhost:26657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx=0x115` or `curl http://localhost:26657/broadcast_tx_commit?tx=115` ? I tired both and was showing errors

Comment: Not sure really. My guess is that it would depend on the backend. Can you try both? The "0x115" makes more sense to me.